# Getting width and height of view of game

Tags: xna, c#

well I have googled it and got some answers, asked many times, answered many times.
as I read viewport is the "inside window"
So I have 2 integers, height and width
and this code:

```
        heightofwindow = graphicsDevice.Viewport.Bounds.Height;
        widtthofwindow = graphicsDevice.Viewport.Bounds.Width;
```

However, I get the error. It doesnt matter if I put it under update or draw. This seems like a more of language problem due to my limited knowlodge.

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: graphicsDevice or Viewport or Bounds is null then

Comment: @Newell, How do you initialize "graphicsDevice"?

Comment: Well apperantly the incorrect way. It seems I've mistaken " GraphicsDeviceManager" for actual graphicsdevice. Can you tell me how can I init. it ? It seems it requires 3 parameters that I havent need until now. I think i can just init. last 2 class with no parameters but how do I init graphicsadapter ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The graphics device manager is created in the game class constructor...

You should use the reference that provides the game instance to access to the GraphicsDevice

if you are inheriting from Game class... in your main class code you can use

```
this.GraphicsDevice.Bounds.Width/Height
```

if you are inheriting from GameComponent... in your component code you can use

```
this.Game.GraphicsDevice.Bounds.Width/Height
```

Comment: how do I init graphicsdevice ? I dont have/dont know how to init graphicsadapter.

Comment: @Newell, when you create a new XNA game project, it does this for you in the generated Game1.cs. Check the constructor of Game1.